# Imagen a base de datos asp.net vb Web

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb

tengo un formulario que "toma fotografías" el formulario está creado con vb de asp.net y la captura de la "fotografía" se hace con javascript y se coloca en un canvas, el problema es que no se como mandar la imagen de los canvas al servidor o poder convertirla a Image de vb y a partir de ahí enviarla a la base de datos.

O si es posible mandar la imagen de esos canvas a un asp:FileUpload, ya que con estos fileupload ya tengo el código para agregar a la base de datos.

Este es FrmRegistrar.aspx ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<body>     

<div id="formRV" runat="server">
    <form id="FrmRegistrarVisita" action="#" method="post" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

        <div id="fotos" class="division">
            <span class="titulo">Fotografias:</span>
            <table id="cameraspic" style="width:100%;text-align:center;" class="tabla"  >
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%;">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkfv" Checked="true" runat="server" visible="false" />
                        <label for="fotovisitante" style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">Visitante:</label>
                        <button id="myBtn" style="width:50%;display:inline-block;" onclick="btnclick();return false;">Ver cámara</button>
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50%;">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkfi" Checked="true" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                        <label for="fotoidentificacion" style="width:50%;display:inline-block;">Identificación: </label>
                        <button id="myBtn2" style="width:50%;display:inline-block;" onclick="btn2click();return false;">Ver cámara</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgvis" runat="server" Width="200px" Visible="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%;">
                        <canvas id="canvas" runat="server" class="sombra" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></canvas>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fotovisitante" capture="camera" accept="image/*" runat="server" Visible="false"  />
                        <asp:Image ID="imagen" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:50%;">
                        <canvas id="canvas2" runat="server" class="sombra" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></canvas>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fotoidentificacion" accept="image/*" capture="camera" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgid" runat="server" Width="200px" Visible="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </div>            
        <asp:Button ID="guardar" Text="Guardar" runat="server" OnClick="guardar_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="FrmRegistrarVisita.aspx" runat="server" id="limpiar" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server">Cancelar</a>
    
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="guardar" />
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="limpiar" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:right;align-self:flex-end;align-content:flex-end;">
        <span class="close btn btn-danger" onclick="spanclick();" style="width:40px;display:inline">&times;</span>
          <button id="btntomar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="tomar();return false;">Tomar foto</button>
          <button id="btntomar2" class="btn btn-success" onclick="tomar2();return false;">Tomar foto</button>
          <video autoplay="autoplay" id="videoElement" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></video>
      </div>
    </div>
     </form>
</div>
<br /><br />

<script>
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
  
   
    function start(e) {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    video.load();
                    video.play();
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.style.display = "block";
                })
                .catch(function (err0r) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
                });
        }
    }
    
    function stop(e) {
        var stream = video.srcObject;
        var tracks = stream.getTracks();
        for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        var track = tracks[i];
        track.stop();
        }
        video.srcObject = null;
    }
    function capture(canvass) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvass);
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);  
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
          const img = new Image();
            window.URL.createObjectURL = function () { };
        });
    }

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
    var btntomar = document.getElementById("btntomar");
    var btntomar2 = document.getElementById("btntomar2");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == document.getElementById("myModal")) {
          document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
          stop();
      }
    }
    function spanclick() {
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        stop();
        return false;
    }

    function btnclick() {
        document.getElementById("btntomar2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("btntomar").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        start();
        return false;
    }
    function btn2click() {
        document.getElementById("btntomar2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("btntomar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        start();
        return false;
    }
    function tomar() {
        capture("canvas");
        stop();
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        return false;
    }
    function tomar2() {
        capture("canvas2");
        stop();
        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        return false;
    }

</script>
```